# Adding Timeout breaks everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have 3 nav buttons that, when hovered over, open a menu underneath. I want to add a timer when then mouse leaves the button so it doesn't close right away after opening. It bugs out a bit then. This is my starter code in jquery, for opening the drop-menu

```
$('.info').hover(function () {
    $('.d-skills').show(500);
    $('.d-info').hide(500);
    $('.d-exp').hide(500);
});
```

If I add this code in it breaks and nothing works

```
function(){ t = setTimeout(function(){$('.d-info').hide(500)}, 500;)
}
```

Also, i add

```
var t;
```

on the very beggining, and i separate the functions with a ','.

'd-info' is the class for the drop menu, and 'info' is the button class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `handlerOut` function for [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Below is a simple snippet that demonstrates this and hides the sections after a 1.5 second delay.

```js
$('.info').hover(function () {
    $('.d-sections').show(500);
}, function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
     $('.d-sections').hide(500);
   }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.d-sections {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
    Hover here for more Information!
    <div class="d-sections">
      <div class="d-skills">
        The D Skills section!
      </div>
      <div class="d-info">
        The D Info section!
      </div>
      <div class="d-exp">
        The D Exp section!
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/32bekom9/1/

Comment: I would like to cancel that .hide if the cursor gets back onto the button as well. And this also bugs out sometimes and closes instantly when the mouse leaves. I believe canceling the .hide would fix that.

Comment: @Mali_Mrav - you would have to take advantage of `.stop()` which would cancel the animation.

Comment: I did try, but that didn't seem to work, and as i understood the .stop() it just cancels the animation if it is in the middle of execution. I would like to have that .hide() not happen at all if the mouse goes back into the div.